# How to solve this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.I tried many ways but could not solve it?

Tags: jdbc

[The image is about the code which I had written to connect sqlplus to eclipse.Which is giving me an error.]

[image]

Comment: Is `ojdbc7.jar` the correct JAR for Oracle, and, if so, can you also verify that this JAR is making it onto your classpath?  The error message says that either you have the wrong JDBC JAR _or_ Java can't see your JAR file.

Comment: It should be `oracle` with a lowercase `o`.

Comment: And for future reference: don't post images of code, post the code as text (formatted as a code block).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regarding Adding libraries in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294415/regarding-adding-libraries-in-eclipse)